# How to change the color of button after click?

Tags: android, button, click

I create button with background color but when i click on it, it's not show anything.
I need to show different color on button after click because user need to know button is
Click.
I don't understand how to do this?
Give me suggestion.
here is my button code.

```
<Button android:textSize="15px"
      android:id="@+id/button9" 
      android:gravity="center|bottom" 
      android:textColor="@color/myWhiteColor" 
      android:drawableTop="@drawable/math"
      android:text="@string/HomePage_Math" 
      android:background="@color/myMaroonColor" 
      android:layout_width="54dp" 
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" ></Button>
```

Comment: use selector http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html

Comment: Use http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/ColorStateList.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

//XML file saved at res/drawable/button_bg.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
          android:color="#ffff0000"/> <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:state_focused="true"
          android:color="#ff0000ff"/> <!-- focused -->
    <item android:color="#ff000000"/> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

//This layout XML will apply the color list to a View:

```
<Button android:textSize="15px"
      android:id="@+id/button9" 
      android:gravity="center|bottom" 
      android:textColor="@color/myWhiteColor" 
      android:drawableTop="@drawable/math"
      android:text="@string/HomePage_Math" 
      android:background="@drawable/button_bg" 
      android:layout_width="54dp" 
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" ></Button>
```

Comment: It show error "tts application has stop unexpectedly"...Not working

Comment: @sandiparmal save that xml in you drawable folder and try it as  android:background="@drawable/button_bg".

Comment: @sandiparmal this error is not related to this code. its different error in you app.

Comment: @SandipArmalPatil if you use drawable instead of color codes in the button_bg xml then you will not get this error "application has stop unexpectedly"

Comment: <item> tag requires a 'drawable' attribute or child tag defining a drawable. This piece of code will not work

Comment: @RajatAnantharam yes you need to report to google soon http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html

Comment: Its an easy fix. Define shape drawables with solid colors of choice for each states. I am in no hurry to report to Google :)

Comment: android:color is not a valid command in <selector> What I did to avoid crashing was create a color.xml file in values and define color in between  <color name="gray">#808080</color>  and give link to that in button_bg.xml .

Comment: @pa1pal  might be you forgot to add inside it in <item>. see the 3rd comments from bottom.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@android:color/holo_green_dark" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/colorCartButton" />
</selector>
```

This will work

Comment: Why will it work? Add some extra details to make it a great answer.