# Clickable layout

Tags: android

I have a clickable linear layout that I've generated programmaticly, and I want it to turn green when it is pressed to indicate that it is clickable, like a button would.  How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a selector.xml file as below...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
          android:color="#ff0000"/> 
    <item android:state_focused="true"
          android:color="#0000ff"/>
    <item android:color="#00ff00"/> </selector>
```

place this xml file in drawable folder. Then set this selector.xml as background of that linearlayout.

Comment: When using the setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selector) to apply, I get an error: 04-03 12:18:15.582: E/AndroidRuntime(13550): Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #4: <item> tag requires a 'drawable' attribute or child tag defining a drawable

Answer (score 1):

you need to create a selector xml file. See link

[How to change the color of button after click?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9685261/how-to-change-the-color-of-button-after-click)

It's a little confusing at first but not too complicated