# android.view.InflateException Binary XML file line #54

Tags: android, xml

I have an ImageButton and I want to make it so the button background changes color when the button is pressed. I have copied the button_bg.xml file from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9685261/1263272) question.

button_bg.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
          android:color="#ffff0000"/> <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:state_focused="true"
          android:color="#ff0000ff"/> <!-- focused -->
    <item android:color="#ff000000"/> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

And line #54 looks like this:

```
<ImageButton
     android:id="@+id/sendButton"
     android:background="@drawable/button_bg"
     android:src="@drawable/ic_action_send_now"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
     android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
```

I have tried removing the line:

```
android:background="@drawable/button_bg"
```

which stops the application crashing but the buttons don't change color.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: possible duplicate of [android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #39: Error inflating class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17347293/android-view-inflateexception-binary-xml-file-line-39-error-inflating-class)

Comment: What version of Android are you testing this on?  I suspect the problem is in the `android:src`, rather than the `android:background`.

Comment: Try adding Drawable x = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.button_bg"); to your Activity#onCreate() method before the setContentView() call.  If it works, your drawable is OK.  If it fails you might get a better error message in logcat.

Comment: Below the InflateException in your stacktrace, there's likely "caused by" exception(s) that describe the specific issue. Please include the complete stacktrace in the question.

Comment: The very first Caused by is as follows: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException. The next one after it says Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/button_bg.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020001

Answer (score 0):

By changning button_bg.xml to the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/clr_pressed"/> <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:state_focused="true"
          android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"/> <!-- focused -->
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"/> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

and adding the following to strings.xml

```
<drawable name="clr_normal">#AAAAAA</drawable>
<drawable name="clr_pressed">#777777</drawable>
```

the problem was solved and the code worked as intended.

Comment: I had been trying to assign to a color attribute when what the correct thing to do was assign it to the background attribute.